# avro-tools-1.8.2 jar conflicts with jakarta.ws.rs-api jar

Tags: java, jar, avro, jakarta-migration, avro-tools

We have an application that has been running for years now and is in production too in multiple places.

We use some functionality from the Jakarta.ws.rs-api.jar file. The following line is of interest though:

```
    Client client;
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(url);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request("application/json");
```

We are now trying to add Avro-tools-1.8.2.jar to our product as we need that for some new features we are implementing. However, I see that when we add this new jar file, the above lines don't work anymore. The line above returns a null WebTarget when we add Avro-tools-1.8.2.jar file to our project. These lines are a problem -

```
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(url);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request("application/json");
```

With the new changes, webTarget shows the following value:

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException: Exception occurred in target VM occurred invoking method.
```

And the line after that crashes.

Looks like there is an exception thrown while creating it.
As mentioned above, if we run this without the Avro-tools jar file, it works perfectly fine.

Unfortunately, we need both Avro and Avro-tools for our new feature. So, removing Avro-tools itself is not an option.

I tried upgrading Avro and Avro-tools to a higher version (1.9.2) to see if it solves the issue. But still see the issue.

In addition, I also checked the contents of the Avro-tools-1.8.2 jar file and see that  it does not have the above problematic classes at all - Client and WebTarget. So, the question of conflict does not arise.

I even tried to see if we can get this done without Avro-tools jar itself. But that is not possible. we read a schema and then convert an incoming JSON to the Avro schema compliant JSON. This functionality needs Avro-tools jar file as per my investigation.

Some questions:

1. Has anyone faced a similar issue? When I do a google search, I don't get anything.
2. Any inputs on how this can be resolved.
3. Lastly, is there a way I can bypass Avro-tools jar itself? I am reading a schema and using that to convert an incoming JSON request to an Avro-compliant JSON. From what I see, both Avro and Avro-tools are needed. (Even though ChatGPT claims otherwise)

Thanks in advance.
Om

---

Update:

I did some investigation and saw the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

I see that a class called javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap exists in both Avro-tools-1.8.2.jar and jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar. However, only jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar has the addAll function mentioned above. Avro-tools-1.8.2.jar does not have that function.

So, it looks like in my case, it may be using the Avro-tools-1.8.2.jar file. Any inputs on how I can fix this? I want my code to pick up Avro-tools-1.8.2.jar at runtime only for some specific classes. Not for the rest. (In code, I am already ensuring this during compilation). The avro-tools-1.8.2.jar and the jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar are both part of a war that has many other jars too.